# MAC Other Volume Issue

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-utility, big-sur, apfs

I am new to MAC and having issue with my Mac. I am getting "no disk space left". I hardly have some GB of data on my MAC, rest is occupied by **other volumes**.

I don't know what's occupying the ramining 172Gi

**diskutil list** output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         202.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         48.7 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +48.7 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Blank⁩                   774.1 KB   disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +202.0 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD - Data⁩     184.1 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 412.2 MB   disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                622.8 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      537.2 MB   disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.3 GB    disk2s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.3 GB    disk2s5s1
   7:                APFS Volume ⁨Windows⁩                 753.7 KB   disk2s8
   8:                APFS Volume ⁨data⁩                    737.3 KB   disk2s9
```

**df -h** output:

```
Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk2s5s1  188Gi   14Gi  2.0Gi    88%  553788 1972110292    0%   /
devfs           198Ki  198Ki    0Bi   100%     684          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk2s4    188Gi   20Ki  2.0Gi     1%       0 1972664080    0%   /System/Volumes/VM
/dev/disk2s2    188Gi  393Mi  2.0Gi    17%    2259 1972661821    0%   /System/Volumes/Preboot
/dev/disk2s6    188Gi  115Mi  2.0Gi     6%      19 1972664061    0%   /System/Volumes/Update
/dev/disk2s1    188Gi  171Gi  2.0Gi    99%  969072 1971695008    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
/dev/disk1s1     45Gi  756Ki   45Gi     1%      98  475432862    0%   /Volumes/Blank
/dev/disk2s9    188Gi  704Ki  2.0Gi     1%      92 1972663988    0%   /Volumes/data
/dev/disk2s8    188Gi  720Ki  2.0Gi     1%      95 1972663985    0%   /Volumes/Windows
map auto_home     0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home
```

**diskutil apfs list** output:

```
APFS Containers (2 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 B6FFA77C-F395-4FC6-841A-DB774C22AE51
|   ====================================================
|   APFS Container Reference:     disk1
|   Size (Capacity Ceiling):      48684335104 B (48.7 GB)
|   Capacity In Use By Volumes:   110280704 B (110.3 MB) (0.2% used)
|   Capacity Not Allocated:       48574054400 B (48.6 GB) (99.8% free)
|   |
|   +-< Physical Store disk0s3 CA66CD3C-C6C1-47F1-917D-D3B7A0C72D9B
|   |   -----------------------------------------------------------
|   |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s3
|   |   Size:                       48684335104 B (48.7 GB)
|   |
|   +-> Volume disk1s1 F01056C2-84A8-4C13-93EF-A2A60F943462
|       ---------------------------------------------------
|       APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (No specific role)
|       Name:                      Blank (Case-insensitive)
|       Mount Point:               /Volumes/Blank
|       Capacity Consumed:         774144 B (774.1 KB)
|       Sealed:                    No
|       FileVault:                 No (Encrypted at rest)
|
+-- Container disk2 7DDDFF95-092C-4140-9979-73F8138FF3DB
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk2
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      202000801792 B (202.0 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   201260204032 B (201.3 GB) (99.6% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       740597760 B (740.6 MB) (0.4% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 52F3C3E6-5F0A-46A8-B46B-A314BB017F29
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       202000801792 B (202.0 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s1 25DB2F25-7BBC-41BB-80FB-BDD8C6EFC803
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s1 (Data)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD - Data (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Data
    |   Capacity Consumed:         184095744000 B (184.1 GB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 Yes (Unlocked)
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s2 7AC5C51A-2FDB-481E-9281-1054279E135B
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Preboot
    |   Capacity Consumed:         412213248 B (412.2 MB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s3 47A9AC6C-652A-459D-B62E-427B3617509C
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         622804992 B (622.8 MB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s4 CB37A2CA-BB66-4F5C-8862-A1A922BFBAC8
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s4 (VM)
    |   Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/VM
    |   Capacity Consumed:         537206784 B (537.2 MB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s5 CB6619CA-6681-438D-BFC0-CC05E4AF7906
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s5 (System)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /System/Volumes/Update/mnt1
    |   Capacity Consumed:         15336370176 B (15.3 GB)
    |   Sealed:                    Broken
    |   FileVault:                 Yes (Unlocked)
    |   Encrypted:                 No
    |   |
    |   Snapshot:                  AA760E8F-E90E-4BC1-8CA5-A861D408554B
    |   Snapshot Disk:             disk2s5s1
    |   Snapshot Mount Point:      /
    |   Snapshot Sealed:           Yes
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s8 E7182D14-5D00-48E3-A46E-6D6AF4463DAA
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s8 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      Windows (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /Volumes/Windows
    |   Capacity Consumed:         753664 B (753.7 KB)
    |   Sealed:                    No
    |   FileVault:                 No (Encrypted at rest)
    |
    +-> Volume disk2s9 2679F61E-1303-4E3E-A97A-642DB555E2DC
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk2s9 (No specific role)
        Name:                      data (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /Volumes/data
        Capacity Consumed:         737280 B (737.3 KB)
        Sealed:                    No
        FileVault:                 No (Encrypted at rest)
```

[image]
[image]

I want to get space back in **/dev/disk2s5s1** where used is 14Gi which is my data but it's showing 2.0 Gi in available and totel is 188Gi.

Update:
[image]

Comment: Are you running macOS Monterey so we can use Disk Utility to check [how much space is locked away in snapshots](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362658/5472)? Select Macintosh HD - Data and then shift command s. [Big Sur I don’t think has that feature.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367158/whats-system-volumes-data)

Comment: That 14Gi on /dev/disk2s5s1 is *not* your data, that's the base OS files. You don't need more space for /dev/disk2s5s1, because that's not where your files are stored. All of your actual files are on /dev/disk2s1, and that's what's taking up most of the space. It looks to me like you just have about 171Gi of user files (and installed applications, and things like that), and that's what's taking up most of the space.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I don't think i have that much data/application installed on this machine, i hardly have some Gi of data on this machine.

Comment: `diskutil list` and `df -h` both show around 171 GiB being used by /dev/disk2s1 aka "Macintosh HD - Data" aka /System/Volumes/Data. That's where user data, installed software, etc goes, and that's where you need to look to see what's taking up all the space.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not going to proscribe any treatment yet. You want to back up everything of importance to you before attempting steps in case you mis-select a “4s2s1”

disk0s3 looks like wasted 48.7 G. You could delete that and grow free space in disk0s2 container. If blank is blank, that should be an easy win.

Same with disk2s8 and disk2s9 - those are small - can you copy off data and remove them?

```
diskutil apfs listsnapshots /System/Volumes/Data/
```

If you recently deleted a bunch of data, snapshots might be holding that space till they purge in time. Also, booting to recovery and repairing that one volume might be prudent.

Comment: I need to know why /dev/disk2s1 is full? i am sure i don't have that much data/App on this machine. I have edited my question and added last screen shot which is showing the size of Apps(Red)=25.23Gi, Documents(Green)=21Gi, System=15Gi and  Other=140Gi. I don't know what this "Other" is, i have MBs of files on this machine.

Comment: Everything is other until spotlight processes it, whatever doesn’t fall into a named category stays grey. Snapshots, data in other user folders (or for which you don’t have permission to read), filesystem corruption, caches that don’t clear. Why not use a tool like DaisyDisk if “manage” doesn’t show you where the space is